# Twilio API to SSIS data flow

Tags: c#, .net, ssis, twilio-api

Attempting to read records from the Twilio API with the aim then to use this in a SSIS Data Flow and save the records in a SQL Server database. Using the API documentation from https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-resource#read-multiple-message-resources I've been able to read the messages but a bit stuck with what to do next, I just want to use this as a source for the Data Flow so not trying to do anything too fancy in .net, more of a SQL guy so not very experienced with C#.

have I been thinking this would be too straight forward? Was assuming i'd be able to read the messages (doesn't look like this comes down as JSON, individual fields have already been split out using the Twilio.dll) put this into a variable which then i loop through each row and pass to the output buffer.

Essentially, was trying something like this:

````
    public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
    {
         string accountSid = "AAAA";

         string authToken = "1111";

        TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

        var response = MessageResource.Read();

        foreach (var msg in response)
        {
            Output0Buffer.AddRow();
            Output0Buffer.ID = msg.Sid.ToString();
            Output0Buffer.Message = msg.Body.ToString();
        }
    }
```
````

Comment: The challenge you're going to run into with the C# approach is that it looks like they want you to install their Twilio library. For SSIS to use external libraries, they need to be installed into the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) - which requires them to be signed. Twilio might sign their assemblies so this might not be a big issue. Package systems like Nuget explicitly don't install into the GAC so developers will build a lovely script that has package dependencies that fail as soon as the editor closes down. Worst case, you could look at using the commandline tool and dumping to text file

Comment: Of course, then you'd need to deal with parsing json and the newtonsoft library to consume it which gets you into the nuget/gac problem

Comment: what version of sql server?  We've had success not using the Twilio library as you can use basic authentication.  We've done a custom script task and then passed the json response out to a stored procedure and used sql server's json junctions to parse the data and load it to a table, but that you need 2016 or later.

Comment: using SQL Server 2017

Comment: It's sometimes not that straight forward dealing with external libraries and SSIS.  Based on your update, do you have that code working in SSIS?  You mentioned "I've been able to read the messages",  how are you doing that?   If you install their Nuget when in the script as soon as you close the reference is lost.  That's what bilinkc is speaking to in his first comment and the challenge here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to get this working in C# eventually. Issue was with the versions of dlls being used where the most recent versions weren't working with each other.

Comment: Could you mention the DLL versions that are incompatible with one another so that people will know in the future.

Comment: Yup sure, below are the DLL versions that work together:
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.5.1.2
Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.1
System.Collections.Specialized.4.3.0
System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.5.1.2
Twilio.5.46.0

The main one not being the most recent is Newtonsoft.Json V10 instead of v12

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example not using the Twilio library and not using a data flow.

We're basically looking at something like:

[image]

1. Truncate the table we're loading
2. We'll use a For Loop Container because we have to account for paging.
3. C# script task to make the REST call
4. Stored procedure to parse the JSON, insert into a table and evaluate the next url value and return that back that out to see if we need to go around again.

Twilio has a default of 50 records, a max of 1000, returned in the response.  You can change that by using URL parameter "?PageSize=60" if you want more than the default.  If there are more records then the specific Page Size the response will include the next url to go get the next set of records.

Two variables:

[image]

NextUrl set as

> [https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{AccountSid}/Messages.json](https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/%7BAccountSid%7D/Messages.json)

For Loop Container

[image]

Once NextUrl = STOP the Loop will stop.  We handle that in the stored procedure.  After we insert the data, we check that value and if it is NULL we set it to STOP.

Script Task
[image]

Pass in the URL, in the script we set apiResponse so it comes back out.

You will need to include these::
[image]

Code for Main()

```
try
            {
                string apiUrl = Dts.Variables["NextUrl"].Value.ToString();

                string userName = ""; //accountSid found in Twilio account console
                string passwd = ""; //authToken found in Twilio account console

                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

                byte[] authToken = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{userName}:{passwd}");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(authToken));

                HttpResponseMessage response;

                // Execute the REST GET
                response = client.GetAsync(apiUrl).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

                // Get the JSON response.
                string contentString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

                Dts.Variables["apiResponse"].Value = contentString; //Passing the response back out.

                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //This code will cause the ssis to fail and bubble back out the error from this code
                Dts.Events.FireError(-1, "Error", ex.Message, String.Empty, 0);
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;

            }
```

Create a stored procedure with a NVARCHAR(MAX) parameter to accept the apiResponse and to return out the NextUrl value.  The task would be something like:

[image]

Parameter Mapping:

[image]

Result Set:

[image]

Then the stored procedure itself would be something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertTwilioMessage]
    @apiResponse NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
    DECLARE @NextUrl NVARCHAR(2000);

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[TwilioMessage] (
                                          [body]
                                        , [num_segments]
                                        , [direction]
                                        , [from]
                                        , [date_updated]
                                        , [price]
                                        , [error_message]
                                        , [uri]
                                        , [account_sid]
                                        , [num_media]
                                        , [to]
                                        , [date_created]
                                        , [status]
                                        , [sid]
                                        , [date_sent]
                                        , [messaging_service_sid]
                                        , [error_code]
                                        , [price_unit]
                                        , [api_version]
                                      )
                SELECT [rsp].[body]
                     , [rsp].[num_segments]
                     , [rsp].[direction]
                     , [rsp].[from]
                     , [rsp].[date_updated]
                     , [rsp].[price]
                     , [rsp].[error_message]
                     , [rsp].[uri]
                     , [rsp].[account_sid]
                     , [rsp].[num_media]
                     , [rsp].[to]
                     , [rsp].[date_created]
                     , [rsp].[status]
                     , [rsp].[sid]
                     , [rsp].[date_sent]
                     , [rsp].[messaging_service_sid]
                     , [rsp].[error_code]
                     , [rsp].[price_unit]
                     , [rsp].[api_version]
                FROM OPENJSON(@apiResponse, '$.messages') --data is in the messages array
                           WITH (
                                    [body] NVARCHAR(255) '$.body'
                                  , [num_segments] NVARCHAR(255) '$.num_segments'
                                  , [direction] NVARCHAR(255) '$.direction'
                                  , [from] NVARCHAR(255) '$.from'
                                  , [date_updated] NVARCHAR(255) '$.date_updated'
                                  , [price] NVARCHAR(255) '$.price'
                                  , [error_message] NVARCHAR(255) '$.error_message'
                                  , [uri] NVARCHAR(255) '$.uri'
                                  , [account_sid] NVARCHAR(255) '$.account_sid'
                                  , [num_media] NVARCHAR(255) '$.num_media'
                                  , [to] NVARCHAR(255) '$.to'
                                  , [date_created] NVARCHAR(255) '$.date_created'
                                  , [status] NVARCHAR(255) '$.status'
                                  , [sid] NVARCHAR(255) '$.sid'
                                  , [date_sent] NVARCHAR(255) '$.date_sent'
                                  , [messaging_service_sid] NVARCHAR(255) '$.messing_serivce_sid'
                                  , [error_code] NVARCHAR(255) '$.error_code'
                                  , [price_unit] NVARCHAR(255) '$.price_unit'
                                  , [api_version] NVARCHAR(255) '$.api_version'
                                ) AS [rsp];


    SELECT @NextUrl = [next_page_uri]
    FROM
           OPENJSON(@apiResponse)
               WITH (
                        [next_page_uri] NVARCHAR(2000) '$.next_page_uri'
                    );

                    -- we check for null of NextUrl and return STOP to stop the for loop
                    --if not we return out the Url to go back around and get more data
    SELECT CASE WHEN @NextUrl IS NOT NULL THEN CONCAT('https://api.twilio.com', @NextUrl)
                ELSE 'STOP'
           END AS [NextUrl];
```

The SSIS variable NextUrl get's overwritten with what is returned back out by the stored procedure.  If that does not equal STOP that continues the for loop, now passing that URL into the script task to go get the next set of data and so on...